# How to programmatically logon to a URL, keep the session, and browse around to different pages

Tags: java, session, cookies, httpclient

I am working on small Java project to programmatically connect to a website with username/password, after login, browse to different links on the site to download some data. First, I need to connect to the website with username/password, 
second, while I keep the session open, go to other links to download data.

How do I do this in Java?

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

Check out the [Apache HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/), it can do all this for you.

Edit: Apache HTTPClient has authentication and cookie handling features included, which will save you a lot of work doing this yourself.

Comment: I am trying HttpClient, it is very easy to connect the site where I am going to scrap data from. couldn't find any example how I can send cookie to the server and keep the session open.

Comment: Sessions are controlled by session cookies, its all explained in the documentation at the link in my post.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract some data [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) can help you a lot it can manage the authentication and also help you with data extraction.

Comment: Great, need to extract data as well. will try HtmlUnit next

Answer (score 0):

1. Investigate with your browser how the web page submits the username/pass data? HTTP Form POST, Ajax, etc..? Use a plugin like Firebug to see network traffic.
2. You can use  URLConnection to create HTTP requests. You will neet to simulate a username/pass login and remember the cookie for use in consequent HTTP requests to simulate a session. Here are some examples: [send HTTP POST request](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/Post.html), [get a cookie](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/GetCookies.html), [send a cookie](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/SendCookie.html).